# How to insert into mysql database an image

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a stage and I've to save images in a db using a BLOB.

I tried to do that:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO cinema_multisala.movie VALUES
('The Lion King', '2021-12-01', '21:00:00', 'description', 'cast', LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/danie/Desktop/LionKing.jpg'), 'producer');
```

But LOAD_FILE always return null, what shall I do? I don't understand my error of the path. I've tried using all of these separator for the path: */*, *\* and *\\*.

(I want to use code and not using *Load Value From File* of MySqlWorkbench, with that I'm able and the image is uploaded correctly)

`secure_file_priv | C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\Uploads\`

Now I put my image in that directory but the query didn't go the same:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO cinema_multisala.movie VALUES ('The Lion King', '2021-12-01', '21:00:00', 'description', 'cast', LOAD_FILE('/LionKing.jpg'), 'producer');`

I've FILE privilege.

SELECT LENGTH(LOAD_FILE('LionKing.jpg')); returns null

Comment: Check does MySQL account have FILE privilege. Check MySQL settings (secure_file_priv, character_set_filesystem). Check does OS account which MySQL service is running from have enough rights for to navigate and read this file. Check does this file is not too large (max_allowed_packet). Check what `SELECT LENGTH(LOAD_FILE('pathname'));` returns. Try to use `INSERT .. SELECT` instead of `INSERT .. VALUES`.

Comment: And you're determined to store images in the database rather than the file system?

Comment: Storing images in a database is almost always a mistake. These are way harder to fetch and serve and complicate your backups. Store file paths, or URLs to some kind of object store, then serve those.

Comment: What does `select LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/danie/Desktop/LionKing.jpg')` return?

Comment: You need to make sure your user has FILE privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Is secure_file_priv variable set?

```
mysql> show variables like "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv |       |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

Comment: There's usually a reason that this is turned off, and casually turning it back on is a *bad plan*.

Comment: Not saying it's a good one but somehow this does not strike me as a public facing project with external users

Comment: It just teaches people to casually ignore stuff like this that can have *huge* consequences if applied in another situation where that's not the case. If someone finds a SQL injection hole and this is turned on, well, congratulations, you've just handed them *EVERYTHING*.

Answer (score 0):

finally everything it works, I did it, I have to put the full path, non only the relative path from secure_file_priv:

```
INSERT INTO cinema_multisala.movie VALUES
    ('title', '2021-12-01', '21:00:00', 'description', 'cast', LOAD_FILE('C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Data\\Uploads\\LionKing.jpg') , 'producer');
```

Strangely I had to modify from BLOB to MEDIUMBLOB, but before using Load Value From File of MySqlWorkbench I was able to upload the same image in a BLOB, don't know why.